# How can I create object and use it in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-x, objective-c-2.0, buildbox

I am using Buildbox for my game. I implemented custom rewarded ads. The problem is that game music continues when rewarded video is open. I want to mute and unmute after video is watched.

I know Java but I am not good in Objective-C and Cocos2dx.

My **AudioEngine.h** Class: under libs/cocos2dx/include/audio/include/

```
/****************************************************************************
 Copyright (c) 2014-2015 Chukong Technologies Inc.

 http://www.cocos2d-x.org

 Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

 The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

 THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 THE SOFTWARE.
 ****************************************************************************/

#include "platform/CCPlatformConfig.h"

#ifndef __AUDIO_ENGINE_H_
#define __AUDIO_ENGINE_H_

#include <functional>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

#include "platform/CCPlatformMacros.h"
#include "audio/include/Export.h"

#ifdef ERROR
#undef ERROR
#endif // ERROR

/**
 * @addtogroup audio
 * @{
 */

NS_CC_BEGIN
    namespace experimental{

/**
 * @class AudioProfile
 *
 * @brief
 * @js NA
 */
class CC_DLL AudioProfile
{
public:
    //Profile name can't be empty.
    std::string name;
    //The maximum number of simultaneous audio instance.
    unsigned int maxInstances;

    /* Minimum delay in between sounds */
    double minDelay;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     *
     * @lua new
     */
    AudioProfile()
    : maxInstances(0)
    , minDelay(0.0)
    {

    }
};

class AudioEngineImpl;

/**
 * @class AudioEngine
 *
 * @brief Offers a interface to play audio.
 *
 * @note Make sure to call AudioEngine::end() when the audio engine is not needed anymore to release resources.
 * @js NA
 */

class CC_DLL AudioEngine
{
public:
    /** AudioState enum,all possible states of an audio instance.*/
    enum class AudioState
    {
        ERROR  = -1,
        INITIALZING,
        PLAYING,
        PAUSED
    };

    static const int INVALID_AUDIO_ID;

    static const float TIME_UNKNOWN;

    static bool lazyInit();

    /**
     * Release objects relating to AudioEngine.
     *
     * @warning It must be called before the application exit.
     * @lua endToLua
     */
    static void end();

    /**  
     * Gets the default profile of audio instances.
     *
     * @return The default profile of audio instances.
     */
    static AudioProfile* getDefaultProfile();

    /** 
     * Play 2d sound.
     *
     * @param filePath The path of an audio file.
     * @param loop Whether audio instance loop or not.
     * @param volume Volume value (range from 0.0 to 1.0).
     * @param profile A profile for audio instance. When profile is not specified, default profile will be used.
     * @return An audio ID. It allows you to dynamically change the behavior of an audio instance on the fly.
     *
     * @see `AudioProfile`
     */
    static int play2d(const std::string& filePath, bool loop = false, float volume = 1.0f, const AudioProfile *profile = nullptr);

    /** 
     * Sets whether an audio instance loop or not.
     *
     * @param audioID An audioID returned by the play2d function.
     * @param loop Whether audio instance loop or not.
     */
    static void setLoop(int audioID, bool loop);

    /** 
     * Checks whether an audio instance is loop.
     *
     * @param audioID An audioID returned by the play2d function.
     * @return Whether or not an audio instance is loop.
     */
    static bool isLoop(int audioID);

    /** 
     * Sets volume for an audio instance.
     *
     * @param audioID An audioID returned by the play2d function.
     * @param volume Volume value (range from 0.0 to 1.0).
     */
    static void setVolume(int audioID, float volume);

    /** 
     * Gets the volume value of an audio instance.
     *
     * @param audioID An audioID returned by the play2d function.
     * @return Volume value (range from 0.0 to 1.0).
     */
    static float getVolume(int audioID);

    /** 
     * Pause an audio instance.
     *
     * @param audioID An audioID returned by the play2d function.
     */
    static void pause(int audioID);

    /** Pause all playing audio instances. */
    static void pauseAll();

    /** 
     * Resume an audio instance.
     *
     * @param audioID An audioID returned by the play2d function.
     */
    static void resume(int audioID);

    /** Resume all suspended audio instances. */
    static void resumeAll();

    /** 
     * Stop an audio instance.
     *
     * @param audioID An audioID returned by the play2d function.
     */
    static void stop(int audioID);

    /** Stop all audio instances. */
    static void stopAll();

    /**
     * Sets the current playback position of an audio instance.
     *
     * @param audioID   An audioID returned by the play2d function.
     * @param sec       The offset in seconds from the start to seek to.
     * @return 
     */
    static bool setCurrentTime(int audioID, float sec);

    /** 
     * Gets the current playback position of an audio instance.
     *
     * @param audioID An audioID returned by the play2d function.
     * @return The current playback position of an audio instance.
     */
    static float getCurrentTime(int audioID);

    /** 
     * Gets the duration of an audio instance.
     *
     * @param audioID An audioID returned by the play2d function.
     * @return The duration of an audio instance.
     */
    static float getDuration(int audioID);

    /** 
     * Returns the state of an audio instance.
     *
     * @param audioID An audioID returned by the play2d function.
     * @return The status of an audio instance.
     */
    static AudioState getState(int audioID);

    /** 
     * Register a callback to be invoked when an audio instance has completed playing.
     *
     * @param audioID An audioID returned by the play2d function.
     * @param callback
     */
    static void setFinishCallback(int audioID, const std::function<void(int,const std::string&)>& callback);

    /**
     * Gets the maximum number of simultaneous audio instance of AudioEngine.
     */
    static int getMaxAudioInstance() {return _maxInstances;}

    /**
     * Sets the maximum number of simultaneous audio instance for AudioEngine.
     *
     * @param maxInstances The maximum number of simultaneous audio instance.
     */
    static bool setMaxAudioInstance(int maxInstances);

    /** 
     * Uncache the audio data from internal buffer.
     * AudioEngine cache audio data on ios,mac, and win32 platform.
     *
     * @warning This can lead to stop related audio first.
     * @param filePath Audio file path.
     */
    static void uncache(const std::string& filePath);

    /** 
     * Uncache all audio data from internal buffer.
     *
     * @warning All audio will be stopped first.
     */
    static void uncacheAll();

    /**  
     * Gets the audio profile by id of audio instance.
     *
     * @param audioID An audioID returned by the play2d function.
     * @return The audio profile.
     */
    static AudioProfile* getProfile(int audioID);

    /**  
     * Gets an audio profile by name.
     *
     * @param profileName A name of audio profile.
     * @return The audio profile.
     */
    static AudioProfile* getProfile(const std::string &profileName);

    /**
     * Preload audio file.
     * @param filePath The file path of an audio.
     */
    static void preload(const std::string& filePath) { preload(filePath, nullptr); }

    /**
     * Preload audio file.
     * @param filePath The file path of an audio.
     * @param callback A callback which will be called after loading is finished.
     */
    static void preload(const std::string& filePath, std::function<void(bool isSuccess)> callback);

protected:
    static void addTask(const std::function<void()>& task);
    static void remove(int audioID);

    struct ProfileHelper
    {
        AudioProfile profile;

        std::list<int> audioIDs;

        double lastPlayTime;

        ProfileHelper()
            : lastPlayTime(0.0)
        {

        }
    };

    struct AudioInfo
    {
        const std::string* filePath;
        ProfileHelper* profileHelper;

        float volume;
        bool loop;
        float duration;
        AudioState state;

        AudioInfo()
            : profileHelper(nullptr)
            , duration(TIME_UNKNOWN)
            , state(AudioState::INITIALZING)
        {

        }
    };

    //audioID,audioAttribute
    static std::unordered_map<int, AudioInfo> _audioIDInfoMap;

    //audio file path,audio IDs
    static std::unordered_map<std::string,std::list<int>> _audioPathIDMap;

    //profileName,ProfileHelper
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, ProfileHelper> _audioPathProfileHelperMap;

    static unsigned int _maxInstances;

    static ProfileHelper* _defaultProfileHelper;

    static AudioEngineImpl* _audioEngineImpl;

    class AudioEngineThreadPool;
    static AudioEngineThreadPool* s_threadPool;

    friend class AudioEngineImpl;
};

}
NS_CC_END

// end group
/// @}

#endif // __AUDIO_ENGINE_H_
```

AdIntegrator class.

```
    #import "AdIntegrator.h"
    #import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
    #include "ads/PTAdController.h"
    #include "cocos2dx/include/audio/include/AudioEngine.h"



   @implementation AdIntegrator

    NSString *rewardedAdUnitId =@"ca-app-pub-0000000000/00000000";

    //Java equality : AudioEngine audio = new AudioEngine(); 


    + (id)shared{
        static AdIntegrator* integrator = nil;
        @synchronized(self){
            if(integrator == nil){
                integrator = [[self alloc] init];
            }
        }
        return integrator;
    }

    #pragma mark Core Methods

    - (void)initAds{
//Java Equality: audio.pauseAll();
        NSLog(@"[Ads] initialization");
        [GADRewardBasedVideoAd sharedInstance].delegate = self;
        [[GADRewardBasedVideoAd sharedInstance] loadRequest:[GADRequest request]
                                               withAdUnitID:rewardedAdUnitId];
    }



    #pragma mark Integration

    @end
```

How can I create object and use its method in Objective-C?

Java Equality:

```
AudioEngine audio = new AudioEngine(); 

audio.pauseAll();
```

How can I do this code in Objective-C?

Comment: This is kinda an "ObjC 101" question.   While an answer to the specific question would be straightforward, you're still going to be lost.   There really isn't a way to line by line convert from one language to another, especially when the underlying SDK changes.

Comment: I am not good in Objective-C I looked from the internet and tried but it gives some errors so I thought asking somebody who knows Objective-C is the best way. My question is simple, how can I create object and use it in another method?

Comment: @gurkanstack use [[object alloc] init] to create object, basically to call a method you use [object method] and to acces the atribute you use object.variable.

Please notice that some object using method or factory stored in the static var create accessed like this Object.shared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. I can mute and unmute in AdIntegrator Class by using:

This will mute all sound.

```
PTAdController::shared()->setMusic(false);
```

This will unmute all sound.

```
PTAdController::shared()->setMusic(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the following code to initialise it.

```
AudioEngine *audio = [[AudioEngine alloc] init];
```

you can use following code to call its method.

```
[audio pauseAll];
```

if you have some code like audio.abc.pausAll then you can call it by simply adding [].

e.g

```
[[audio abc] pauseAll];
```

Comment: As a quick note here. This code will not work since `AudioEngine` is C++ code. The code in this answer is treating `AudioEngine` as an Obj-C class, which it is not.

Answer (score 5):

`AudioEngine` is a C++ class. You will be calling C++ from Obj-C. In particular, the `AudioEngine`'s methods are static functions, so there is no "object" to create.

You should pause and resume as opposed to mute and unmute, since mute would continue playback and simply set the volume to 0. Additionally, pausing is easier based the functions avail in the `AudioEngine` header you listed. Volume control requires knowing the `audioID` which would require some tracking to ensure that all playing audio is muted/unmuted.

When you want to pause, just call:

```
experimental::AudioEngine::pauseAll();
```

To resume, just call:

```
experimental::AudioEngine::resumeAll();
```

As an FYI, it is possible you may need to use the `cocos2d` namespace as well. Which means `experimental` would change to `cocos2d::experimental`.

Another caveat is that your Obj-C code must be compiled as Objective-C++ source.

There are two ways to do this.

1. The source file uses the `.mm` extension.
2. The type of the file set in the File Inspector in Xcode is
   explicitly set to `Objective-C++ Source`. `.m` files will be listed
   as `Objective-C Source`. To do this, select the file in the Project Navigator and then choose View:Inspectors:Show File Inspector in the menu. The File Inspector, if not already present, will show up on the far right.

Comment: It is not working. It gives this error.

https://i.ibb.co/W3PJQhV/b.png

Comment: Have you tried to use `cocos2d::experimental` instead of `experimental`? You need to find what the correct C++ namespace is for it.  I assume your file is also setup for ObjectiveC++ source?

Comment: Yes, it gives this error. 

https://i.ibb.co/jRNrFDp/1.png

My top.. 

https://i.ibb.co/frFKJr0/2.png

Comment: How to find correct C++ namespace? I do not know source it is buildbox, it uses cocos2d